# when it come to TLS on FTP which port need to be allow?

Tags: firewall

we have some issues that am not sure if it port need to be allow on my mikrotik or just a issues from the FTP server the are using TLS encryption to have access but we can't connect is there any port beside of 21 need to be open ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normal FTP uses port 21(TCP/UDP) for control and port 20(TCP/UDP) for data.
FTP over TLS (FTPS) uses port 990(TCP/UDP) for control and port 989(TCP/UDP) for data.

You will need to open both as FTPS prevents the router from detecting which port was negotiated for the data transfer.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Port 990 is for implicit FTPS (not recommended anymore). Explicit FTPS uses 21 by default.